# C++ pointers to object in a vector creates dangling pointers

Tags: c++, mfc

OK, I will try again.
Simplified code:

```
vector<CMFCPropertyGridProperty*> propertyVector;

BOOL CSysMap1Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CMFCPropertyGridProperty * pGroupTest = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty("Title");

//adding sub items etc

propertyVector.push_back(pGroupTest);
}

void CSysMap1Dlg::OnBnClickedShowButton()
{
m_PropertyGrid.AddProperty(propertyVector.at(0)); //take note
}
```

I am creating a CMFCPropertyGridProperty object and I want to store it in a vector (propertyVector). 
The constructor for CMFCPropertyGridProperty is `CMFCPropertyGridProperty * pGroupTest` not `CMFCPropertyGridProperty pGroupTest`.

On button click I'm diplaying propertyGrid.

I hard coded 0 just for this example. The program starts, creates CMFCPropertyGridProperty object, pushes it on vector. User clicks ShowButton. The program displays the property grid (propertyvector has one object at(0)). User clicks ShowButton again, the program crashes. I tried to debug it, after the second click the propertyVector.at(0) points to 0x0000000.

All code in show button:

```
void CSysMap1Dlg::OnBnClickedShowButton()
{
    int row = m_List.GetCurSel();
    //clear grid
    m_PropertyGrid.RemoveAll();

    //set column width
    CRect rect;
    m_PropertyGrid.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    m_PropertyGrid.PostMessage(WM_SIZE, 0, MAKELONG(rect.Width(),rect.Height()));

    m_PropertyGrid.AddProperty(propertyVector.at(row));

    m_PropertyGrid.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: Set a data breakpoint and check when it gets modified.

Comment: What does `m_PropertyGrid.AddProperty` does with the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty*` ..? Can you post code for that function as well.?

Comment: m_PropertyGrid is just my control variable of MFC PropertyGrid Control.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I haven't used data breakpoint before. It shows that memory changes in afx.inl CObject destructor

Comment: Doesn't `m_PropertyGrid.RemoveAll()` **delete** all properties? From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983781.aspx) - When you are done with the property grid control, call CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::RemoveAll **to delete** all the added properties.

Comment: I commented out `m_PropertyGrid.RemoveAll()` the program still crashes. RemoveAll() just clears the grid. The problem must be with pointers. Am I using them correctly?